# PHP variables in mysql query

Tags: mysql, wpdb

What is the consensus on how to insert variables in a MySQL query using the `$wpdb->insert` syntax: `($table, array($column=>$value),$format)`?

I know this hasn't worked:

```
$wpdb->update('wp_mytable',
array('product'=>"$product"));
```

Nor this:

```
$wpdb->update('wp_mytable',
array('product'=>$product));
```

Nor this:

```
$insert_row = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO wp_mytable
                                                       ( product )
                                                       VALUES (%s)
                                                       ",
                                                       $product));
```

Where echoing $product indeed echoes the string I want to insert.

The other syntax that has worked for me in the past (but not via the $wpdb syntax) is:

```
INSERT INTO wp_mytable ('product') VALUES '%s', $product;
```

I'm still getting a blank field value in the database with all above methods. The row is created but the value is missing.

-- **Update**

```
$insert_row = $wpdb->insert( 'wp_mytable',
                                        array( 'product' => $product,
                                                'votes' => 1),
                                        array(  '%s', '%d' )
                                        );
```

This still produces a blank entry under the product column. The vote is counted for the row but the product field is left blank.

This is how I declare $product:

```
$product = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID,'product');
$product = strval($product[0]->name);
```

I'm selecting the first object term's name and making sure it's a string.

Also what's interesting about the update query is that although the WHERE clause has its own array, it requires an AND for multiple clauses. This is confusing if you are declaring variables for the WHERE parameters:

```
$update_vote = $wpdb->update( 'wp_mytable',
                                         array( 'votes' => $new_votes ),
                                         array( 'product' => $product
                                                'company' => $company), // WHERE DOES 'AND' GO?
                                         array( '%d' ),
                                         array( '%s', '%s' )


                                         );
```

Comment: The `$where` parameter of `$wpdb->update()` does **not** require an "AND". This is a misconception. The method will join those where clauses by an "AND". From the codex: *A named array of WHERE clauses (in column => value pairs). Multiple clauses will be joined with ANDs. Both $where columns and $where values should be "raw".*

Comment: As for the empty DB field: What does `var_dump($product);` yield and what data type have you chosen for the 'product' column in the DB? Also, if this is now about the usage of `wp_get_object_terms()` it should have been asked in a new question, btw.

Comment: var_dump returns 'string(7) "Product Name"'

Comment: I posted the question here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55023/wp-get-object-terms-returning-string-for-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To [insert a new row](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_rows):

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert( 
    'wp_mytable',
    array( 'product' => $product ),
    array( '%s' ) 
);
```

For the sake of completeness, `$wpdb->update` is used to [update an existing row](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows) and requires an additional WHERE clause, as would a "regular" SQL query. For example:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->update( 
    'wp_mytable',
    array( 'product' => $product ),
    array( 'product_id' => 1312 ),
    array( '%s' ),
    array( '%d' )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm still facing the same problem however. $product is still blank even after I confirm that it's a string: $product= wp_get_object_terms($post->ID,'product'); $product= strval($product[1]->name);